# Is it possible to wrap a small package not listed on MELPA/ELPA via use-package? How to do it?

Tags: package, use-package, cursor, install, centering

I like this Emacs package called **Emacs Centered Point** [link](https://github.com/jmercouris/emacs-centered-point). I must highlight that it is not listed on MELPA/ELPA.

Until now, I have just appended the snippet to my init file with the following and it works:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode centered-point-mode
  "Alaways center the cursor in the middle of the screen."
  :lighter "..."
  (cond (centered-point-mode (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'pmd/line-change))
    (t (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'pmd/line-change))))

(defun pmd/line-change ()
  (when (eq (get-buffer-window)
            (selected-window))
    (recenter)))

(provide 'centeredpoint)
(centered-point-mode t) ;;enable it globally
```

But, I have been completely re-writing my init file to be as declarative as possible with [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package).

And now I am unsure about how to handle this package since it is not on MELPA/ELPA.

*Ceteris paribus* (other things equal), is it possible to wrap this with use-package? If possible, how to do so?

Would it be even more verbose than keeping things as they are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use `use-package`, and it will be less verbose than including the entire snippet.

You will need to basically add the `centeredpoint.el` file to Emacs `load-path`. One option is to download `centeredpoint.el` at some place, and then use the `:load-path` keyword.

```
(use-package centeredpoint
  :load-path "path-to-centeredpoint.el" ; relative path will work
  :hook (after-init . centered-point-mode))
```

The following snippet uses [`straight.el`](https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el) as the package manager.

```
(use-package centeredpoint
  :straight (centered-point-mode :type git :host github 
                                 :repo "jmercouris/emacs-centered-point")
  :hook (after-init . centered-point-mode))
```

It is possible to use [`quelpa`](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa-use-package) with `use-package` along with Emacs' default package manager to install packages automatically that are not on MELPA/ELPA. The other alternative is to write your own function with `package-install`.